# How to invoke authenticate from a controller - spring security core plugin

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I am using spring security core plugin v2 on grails 2.5. My question is regarding methods for how would one go about authenticating a user that has provided their login details via an ajax submit to a controller?

For example, a user signs up via an ajax call and the controller which handles this signup process ensures that the user that has just signed up is automatically authenticated in the session.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to authenticate the user from my controller by calling springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password"));